# Hide back button in MWPhotoBrowser navigationcontroller

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, backbarbuttonitem, mwphotobrowser

I am using `MWPhotoBrowser` in my ARC project. Everything is working fine. I want to hide back button. In `performLayout()` function, I tried below code to hide back button but its not working.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MWPhotoBrowser.m** find the following line:

```
self.previousViewControllerBackButton = previousViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

and change it to:

```
self.previousViewControllerBackButton = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

@KingPolygon, @iOSDev.
As my account is short of minimum reputations to comment, so I am using this option.

I have done it same as you described but, backButton doesn't removed on my side.

//_previousViewControllerBackButton = previousViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;        _previousViewControllerBackButton = nil;

I did above in -performLayout;

Comment: what would be the solution if,  _previousViewControllerBackButton is 'nil' in -performLayout?

Comment: Now, i have reference to my viewController in previousViewController and i have done above given steps: still backButton does not hide.